# How to map a letter key like('w') to a function key like('F6')?

Tags: autohotkey

My 'w'key on my keyboard is not working so I wanted to remap it to the 'F6'. But when I write

```
w::F6
return
```

in the .ahk file and run it. Still no results are to be found.
Can anyone please help me to fix this issue?(Its literally to time wasting to use onscreen keyboard just to type w key)
Thank you

Comment: just a guess ... maybe you have to remap both ways

Comment: The syntax `w::F6` means you'd get `F6` by pressing `w`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*w::
SetKeyDelay -1   ; If the destination key is a mouse button, SetMouseDelay is used instead.
Send {Blind}{F6 DownR}  ; DownR is like Down except that other Send commands in the script won't assume "F6" should stay down during their Send.
return

*w up::
SetKeyDelay -1  ;
Send {Blind}{F6 up}
return
```

Comment: Please add missing details like framework used (AutoHotKey) and platform (Windows?) as it's not clear from question/answer